# JavaFX Boolean Binding and TableView Binding multiple

Tags: button, javafx, binding

I want to bind a Button to two specific constraints.

One of them is already implemented:

```
deleteGroupage.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));
```

This is for my tableView that u can't press the button to delete something, when nothing is selected to avoid a Nullpointer.
But now i also got a static login variable, which tells if the user is a guest == false or if he is logged in == true.

```
boolean loggedIn = LoginController.loggedIn;
```

How can i bind this both? The user needs to be loggedIn and selected a row in the table.

```
details.setDisable(loggedIn);
```

This won't work because the binding is more relevant for Java then this setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Bindings.or`

like:

```
deleteGroupage.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()).or(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> !LoginController.loggedIn));
```

or:

```
deleteGroupage.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.or(Bindings.isEmpty(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()),Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> !LoginController.loggedIn)));
```

or using **fabian**'s suggestion for efficiency:

```
deleteGroupage.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty() || !LoginController.loggedIn, tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));
```

By using this solution I assume that the information `LoginController.loggedIn` is already there when you are binding this to the button's `disaableProperty()`

**Edit: Sorry, you have to use `or` instead of `and` and it should work. I've corrected it**

Comment: Okay nevermind it does not work correctly. When i am loggedIn but have not selected a row i still can press the button @Sunflame

Comment: For the first version i get the error: cannot invoke and (BooleanBinding) on the primitive type void @Sunflame

Comment: Answer updated. If you need, I can paste the whole example I've wrote.

Comment: Why create multiple bindings, if a single one will do? `Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty() || !LoginController.loggedIn, tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems())`

Comment: Yeah, true, its more efficient.

Comment: @Sunflame Again one question. I want to bind again a Button to a boolean loggedIn value and the value of a comboBox that cant be null, so something must me selected. I tried many things, but it's not the same as the tableView. Without the loggedIn variable it works like that anwesend.disableProperty().bind(studentenauswahlBox.valueProperty().isNull());

Comment: You can implement the same way we have suggested this solution.

Comment: Nop i can't. Already tried. I wouldn't answer if it would work @Sunflame